# Using values from reactive expression R Shiny Files on data frames

Tags: r, dataframe, shiny

I am using Shiny Files to analyse the content from folders and this is the expression I use to obtain the folder path, the list of files in the folder and the length of that list.

```
folderInput1<- reactive({
    shinyDirChoose(input, 'directory', roots= volumes, session=session,     restrictions=system.file(package='base'))
return(parseDirPath(volumes, input$directory))})

files1 <- reactive({
list.files(path = folderInput1(), pattern = "*.csv", full.names = T)
})

nFiles1 <- reactive({ length(files1() ) })
```

I'm having trouble while trying to to use this information in data frames. This is what I am trying to do:

```
folder_df = data.frame(matrix(0,ncol = 4, nrow = nFiles1()))
```

I'm getting this error message:

> Error in matrix(0, ncol = 4, nrow = nFiles1()) : non-numeric matrix
>   extent

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so first `shinyDirChoose` is a reactive. So you do not need to wrap it in a reactive. Then, you obtain the value of this `shinyDirChoose` via input, `input$directory` in your case.

Next, extracting the path is a bit weird because it is stored in a list. Here is an example, I hope it makes things clear.

So the value that you were getting for `nFiles1()` was probably NULL.

#### ui

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyFiles)

shinyUI(fluidPage(

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      shinyDirButton("dir", "dirButton", "title", buttonType = "default", class = NULL)
    ),

    mainPanel(
      h3("input$dir"),
      verbatimTextOutput("view"), br(),
      h3("files"),
      verbatimTextOutput("info")
    )
  )
))
```

#### server

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyFiles)

shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  shinyDirChoose(input, "dir", roots = c(home = '~'))
  output$view <- renderPrint(input$dir)

  info <- reactive({
    dash <- .Platform$file.sep
    list.files(path = paste("~", paste(unlist(input$dir$path)[-1], collapse = dash), sep = dash), 
               pattern = "*.csv", full.names = TRUE)
  })
  output$info <- renderPrint(length(info()))

})
```

Comment: I've tried to run this code and it's not working properly.

Comment: `Warning: Error in observerFunc: argument "session" is missing, with no default
Stack trace (innermost first):
    54: observerFunc
     1: shiny::runApp
ERROR: [on_request_read] connection reset by peer`

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to recreate your error. Here, the code is working fine. Does it help if you put `session` as a third argument in the `shinyServer()` function?